# Django - Admin user only able to create data. FOREIGN KEY constraint failed for normal users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-allauth

I'm creating a simple CRUD application to brush up on my Django skills (it's been a long time!) but I'm getting the below errors when I have a non-admin users create anything, either via the frontend or the sites backend:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

I'm also getting this error when I'm logged in as the admin user and try to update the user field in the Django Admin panel.

The functionality itself works, as I can create activities through the frontend and backend when I'm logged in as the superuser.  I've also tried deleting migrations etc.. but there doesn't seem to be any resolutions.

The site itself uses Django's allauth models, but with custom models to fit the general purpose, but I'm still using the AllAuth user model as my foreign key, as the other model is a UserProfile:

Below is my models.py file for the activities:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Activities'

    activity_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="activity")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time =models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=False, blank=False)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.activity_id)
```

With the view:

```
def create_activity(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ActivityForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.host = request.user
            activity = form.save(commit=False)
            activity.save()
            return redirect('activities')
    else:
        form = ActivityForm()
        context = {
        'form': form,
    }
        return render(request, 'activities/new_listing.html', context)
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different methods of adding data after form validation. Unfortunately you are saving the method that has no data added.  I've commented out those lines

```
    if form.is_valid():
        #activity = form.save(commit=False)
        #you would also need: activity.host = request.user
        #activity.save()
        form.instance.host = request.user
        form.save()
```

Here I've chosen to go with the form.instance method (because of https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-commit-false-when-altering-the-instance-in-a-modelform.html) which should make things work.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to resolve the issue, I've been looking into it some more and it seems to be related to the specific user account, but looks like it's all user accounts that have since been created, so back to the drawing board!